Excel - how to return next highest figure in a column but only from a row below that specific number

I’ve found a number of threads to return the next largest number from a column and have obtained that using a combination of index, match, small and rank functions. However, I only want to return values from rows below a specified row.
Below is an example table. I’d like to return 12 from here when trying to obtain the next largest value after L2’s 278.



contract
qty




L 1
25


L 2
278


L 3
12


L 4
6



It is not possible to remove unwanted rows from the table as this is a constantly refreshing table of available data.
I used:
=INDEX(Table1[contract],MATCH(IFERROR(SMALL(Table1[qty],RANK.EQ(VLOOKUP(“L2”,Table1[[contract]:[qty]],2, FALSE),Table1[qty],1)+1,SMALL(Table1[qty],RANK.EQ(VLOOKUP(“L2”,Table1[[contract]:[qty]],2, FALSE),Table1[qty],1)-1)),Table1[qty],0)


Can you mock up the expected result in the context of the spreadsheet? in which cell should the formula  go? If that formula returns 278, where, then, in which cell will the next formula be located? It's great that you posted a data sample for easy copy pasting, but please post a screenshot of the desired result in the worksheet.

Thanks for the quick response @teylyn I've now added a screenshot of the spreadsheet. I need to return "L 3" in cell H5, not "L 1"

This formula:
=MAX(INDEX(A2:B8,MATCH(D1,A2:A8,0)+1,2):B8)

the cell address B8 is to be replaced the last cell address in column B.
A2:B8 and A2:A8 are the respective ranges of data and column A.

